# Java compile warnings with spring "Validator" classes

Tags: java, spring

New to spring, we have a whole pile of validators that generate java warnings, I was able to hide them using the "@SuppressWarnings" annotation, however what is the proper way to sort this out?

```
public class SignInValidator implements
        org.springframework.validation.Validator {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return clazz.equals(SignInCredentials.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372595/class-is-a-raw-type-references-to-generic-type-classt-should-be-parameterized) explains why this happens.  That Spring Validator is still Java 1.4 compliant, so clazz has to be a raw `Class` with no generic type.  However, per the [Spring 3.0 javadocs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html), Validator's supports method has been updated to take a `Class<?>`, so it would remove this error.