# Raw type. References to generic types should be parameterized

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have a Cage class:

```
public class Cage<T extends Animal> {
// the construtor takes in an integer as an explicit parameter
...
}
```

I am trying to instantiate an object of Cage in another class main method:

```
private Cage cage5 = new Cage(5);
```

I get the error: Cage is a raw type. References to generic type Cage should be parameterized. I tried several ideas, but am stuck about this tricky syntax :o(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372595/class-is-a-raw-type-references-to-generic-type-classt-should-be-parameterized)

Comment: Please do not edit your question to invalidate answers.  If you have a new problem, open a new question.  Since you've removed the original question and replaced it with a new one, my answer no longer makes sense.  I have rolled back the question.

Comment: Sorry, I will open a new question.

Comment: No problem, everyone is new once. :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Cage<T>` is a generic type, so you need to specify a type parameter, like so (assuming that there is a `class Dog extends Animal`):

```
private Cage<Dog> cage5 = new Cage<Dog>(5);
```

You can use any type that extends `Animal` (or even `Animal` itself).

If you omit the type parameter then what you wind up with in this case is essentially `Cage<Animal>`.  However, you should still explicitly state the type parameter even if this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks cdhowie. I am sorry, I had several diff things I was trying. I am having a more stubborn error edited now. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

For other java newbie like me.

- Code is look like this:

```java
public class ContinuousAddressBuilder<T> extends VariableLengthPacket {
  ...

  /* T=int/float/double */
  private ArrayList<T> informosomes;

  ...

  public ContinuousAddressBuilder builderCon(int con) {
    ...
  }
}
```

- Solution:

Add `<T>` after your class:

change from

`public ContinuousAddressBuilder builderCon(int con)`

to

`public ContinuousAddressBuilder<T> builderCon(int con)`