# Array - Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized

Tags: java

I have a following array:

```
public static Class[] GLOBAL_FEATURE_EXTRACTORS = {
            CEDD.class,
            AutoColorCorrelogram.class
}
```

and right now I have a following warning:

```
Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized
```

Both `CEDD` and `AutoColorCorrelogram` classes implements `GlobalFeature` interface

How to correctly parameterize `Class[]` in order to avoid this warning ?

Comment: use `Class<GlobalFeature>[]`? But I suggest you use a List or a Set

Comment: Class<GlobalFeature>[] GLOBAL_FEATURE_EXTRACTORS - fails with a following compilation error: 
Cannot create a generic array of Class<GlobalFeature>

Comment: @RC. I don't think that'd work. Probably something like `Class<?>[]`...

Comment: Generic arrays aren't supported in java:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays

Comment: I usually use guava ImmutableList.of() for this kind of constants, so not sure about arrays. Should this be closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952283/raw-type-references-to-generic-types-should-be-parameterized?rq=1 ?

Comment: Class<?>[] works fine, thanks.

Comment: I recommend using a collection, which can be typed, eg `public static List<Class<? extends Number>> FOO = Arrays.asList(Integer.class, Long.class);`