# List<Map> References to generic type Map<K,V> should be parameterized

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Why I'm Getting this Mark in my Eclipse project? can someone explain me? or give me a fix for it

- Map is a raw type. References to generic type Map should be parameterized
- Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List

```
public Integer getAgenteId(Integer agente) {

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT id_agente FROM callcenter.agente WHERE agente = ? ";
        EntityManager em = PersistenceUtil.getEntityManager();
        Query q  = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
        q.setHint(QueryHints.RESULT_TYPE, ResultType.Map);
        List<Map> lm = q.getResultList(); // ECLIPSE MARK HERE

        for (Map rs : lm) { // ANOTHER ECLIPSE MARK HERE

            return (Integer)rs.get("id_agente");

        }

        return null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Erro (GetAgenteId) : " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}
```

Edit: I don't want to supress warning, I want to fix the Warning.

Comment: You have to parameterize `Map` like `Map<K,V>` where K and V are your key and value types respectively.

Comment: You have to write : List<Map<K,V>>, with the types of what you get back

Comment: You'll still get the second warning, though. `Query` simply isn't parameterized, and consequently, `q.getResultList()` does not return a typed `List`. What you need is a cast: `List<Map<String, Object>> lm = (List<Map<String, Object>>) q.getResultList();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372595/class-is-a-raw-type-references-to-generic-type-classt-should-be-parameterized)